# Mule 3.9 - Remove few XML tags from the payload while preserving the namespaces & attributes

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have to remove few fields from the XML payload.But it should not remove the attributes and namespaces in the XML. I wrote a function below but it is removing the attributes and namespaces.

Output XML should not contain userId and companyID those 2 tags should be removed wherever it is present.

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <axis2ns1873:messageheader xmlns:axis2ns1873=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001 soapenv:mustUnderstand="false">
            <ns5:providerService xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>
                <ns5:name>SVC</ns5:name>
                <ns5:operation>auditLogPublish</ns5:operation>
            </ns5:providerService>
            <ns5:component xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001> Payments</ns5:component>
            <ns5:activity xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001> Payment</ns5:activity>
            <ns5:channel xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>p</ns5:channel>
            <ns5:traceId xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>e995d4fb-54d4-4d34-b56a-e0594578db0c</ns5:traceId>
            <ns5:applicationId xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>Payments</ns5:applicationId>
            <ns5:userId xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>user</ns5:userId>
            <ns5:companyId xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>cy</ns5:companyId>
            <ns5:companyType xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001></ns5:companyType>
            <ns5:clientMachineId xmlns:ns5=http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001>localhost</ns5:clientMachineId>
        </axis2ns1873:messageheader>
        <axis2ns1874:messageheader xmlns:axis2ns1874=http://host/xsd/cpsMessageTypes/V002 soapenv:mustUnderstand="false" guid="1ce23ccc-eb30-4fcc-9b1f-927c46921e34" traceId="1ce23ccc-eb30-4fcc-9b1f-927c46921e34" />
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:approvePayments xmlns:ns2=http://host/xsd/service/V002>
            <ns2:payment>
                <ns2:MID></ns2:MID>
                <ns2:version>1</ns2:version>
                <ns2:documentType></ns2:documentType>
            </ns2:payment>
            <ns2:OTPValidated>SUCCESS</ns2:OTPValidated>
            <ns2:userInfo>
                <ns2:companyId> </ns2:companyId>
                <ns2:userId> </ns2:userId>
                <ns2:userType>CLIENT</ns2:userType>
            </ns2:userInfo>
            <ns2:userSiteminderSessionId>id=</ns2:userSiteminderSessionId>
            <ns2:userIpAddress>localhost</ns2:userIpAddress>
        </ns2:approvePayments>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

`%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
 
%function remove(content, y)
((content mapObject (value,key) -> ({}
   when ((y contains (key as :string)) and (value is :string or value is :boolean or value is :number)) otherwise ((key): remove(value,y))
)) when (content is :object) otherwise ((content map remove($,y))
   when (content is :array) otherwise (content)
))
---
remove(payload,  flowVars.filterList)`
```

How to fix this? TIA!

Comment: Please provide an example input and actual and expected outputs.

Comment: The XML input is missing the quotes around the attribute values, the XML is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The script is missing to map the attributes from the input when transforming an object. That can be done inside the `mapObject` operation by setting the attributes to `(key.@)` which returns the attributes from that key.

Note that this kind of recursive function is much more clearly expressed using the pattern matching operator `match`.

Example:

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%function remove(content, filterList)
    content match {
        :array -> $ map (value,index) -> remove(value, filterList),
        :object -> $ mapObject (value,key) ->
            (key) @((key.@)) : {} 
                when (someConditions ...) // add conditions here
                otherwise remove(value, filterList)
            ,
        default -> content
    }
---
remove(payload, ["x","y"])
```

I'm just showing the general method. You'll need to adapt to your condition.

You could additionally create a closure or function to parametrize the condition out of the `remove()` function.

Comment: How to apply the same logic to attributes and values? I tried with below but it is not working when the offended fields in values. ` 
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%function remove(content, filterList)
    content match {
        :array -> $ map (value,index) -> remove(value, filterList),
        :object -> $ mapObject (value,key) ->
            (key) @((key.@)) : null when (filterList contains (key as :string))
                otherwise remove(value, filterList),
        default -> content
    }
---
remove(payload, ["beneAccount","bankId"])`

Comment: it is not preserving all the attributes from the XML. it just preserves the first attribute